# How to use two dictionaries (.dic & .aff files) at the same time in texmaker?

Tags: texmaker, languages, spelling, dictionaries, grammar

I'm often writing documents in different languages and I like to use the autocorrection in texmaker. But its very annoying, if you always have to switch the dictionary file.

So I tried the following: I copyied one .dic-file (e.g. de_DE.dic) and the corresponding grammar-file (de_DE.aff) in to my current working directory. Then I opened another language's dic (en_GB.dic) copied everything and inserted it into de_DE.dic. That works pretty well. Now all words are known in their original form. I tried the same for the .aff -file to have both grammars, but without success :(

Does anyone have an idea how to handle this problem?

I am aware, that using two languages at the same time with this approach will lead to acceptance of some wrong forms. But nevertheless I think it would help me to avoid some typos.

Comment: Not sure if this works with texmaker, but with texstudio one can insert comments like `% !TeX spellcheck = en_GB` in the .tex file to conveniently switch between languages on a file by file basis.

Comment: @samcarter, I'm not sure either, but I believe the OP means multiple languages within the same file. I can relate, I've been in the same situation and wished for the same thing.

Comment: If I remember correctly, [Arachnophilia](https://arachnoid.com/arachnophilia/index.html) can use several dictionaries at the same time, but is a general purpose plain text  editor.  On the other hand, texworks cannot use two dictionaries at the same time, but allows a quick switch among all available dictionaries via menu Edit, (only three mouse clicks, without having to write  anything in the Settings).

Answer (score 0):

- As far as I know that is **not possible**.
- I use a **different approach**, where I **copy & paste the text** from time to time into **Microsoft Word** or another word processor.